Unable to Reset Camera Pose to Zero Orientation in AFRAME Scene in VR mode in Quest 3 device
I'm encountering an issue where I cannot fully reset the camera pose, particularly the orientation, in an AFRAME scene. Despite resetting the camera's rotation to zero, the tracking offset from the headset is maintained, causing the camera to retain its previous orientation.
I am using a wrapper around the AFRAME camera to add rotation offsets and even resetting the look-controls component when in UI mode to move the camera. However, the issue persists and the camera does not reset to the expected zero orientation.
Here is the function I use to reset the scene camera's rotation:
const resetAframeSceneCameraRotation = () => {
  const scene = AFRAME.scenes[0];
  const sceneThreeCamera = scene.camera;
  if (!sceneThreeCamera || !sceneThreeCamera.el) {
    console.error('No se encontró la cámara de la escena.');
    return;
  }

  const sceneAframeCamera = scene.camera.el as Entity;
  const zeroRotation = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

  sceneAframeCamera.setAttribute('rotation', zeroRotation);

  _sceneWrapper = getSceneWrapper();
  if (_sceneWrapper) {
    _sceneWrapper.setAttribute('rotation', zeroRotation);
  }

  const controls = sceneAframeCamera.components['look-controls'] as any;
  if (controls) {
    controls.pitchObject.rotation.x = 0;
    controls.yawObject.rotation.y = 0;
  }
};

I understand that I might need to reset the XR session and the camera pose somehow, but so far, I have not been able to achieve this. The traditional method of requesting a session does not seem to work, and I can't figure out how to set the camera's transform to zero.
Here is an example of what I attempted to do:
if (scene.renderer?.xr?.isPresenting) {
  const xrSession = scene.renderer.xr.getSession();
  if (xrSession) {
    resetSessionViewerPose(xrSession);
  }
}

const resetSessionViewerPose = (xrSession: XRSession) => {
  xrSession.requestReferenceSpace("local").then((xrReferenceSpace) => {
    xrSession.requestAnimationFrame((time, xrFrame) => {
      const viewerPose = xrFrame.getViewerPose(xrReferenceSpace);
      if (viewerPose) {
        const inverseOrientation = new DOMPointReadOnly(-viewerPose.transform.orientation.x, -viewerPose.transform.orientation.y, -viewerPose.transform.orientation.z, viewerPose.transform.orientation.w);
        const inversePosition = new DOMPointReadOnly(-viewerPose.transform.position.x, -viewerPose.transform.position.y, -viewerPose.transform.position.z);

        const resetTransform = new XRRigidTransform(inversePosition, inverseOrientation);
        const resetReferenceSpace = xrReferenceSpace.getOffsetReferenceSpace(resetTransform);

        console.log('WebXR session reset with inverse viewer pose.');
      } else {
        console.warn('Exp360 Viewer: No valid viewer pose obtained.');
      }
    });
  });
};


